# Open link in default browser from Android WebView with HTML or Javascript only

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

Is there a way to force Android Webview to open a web page in the default browser with no changes to the Webview - meaning the code will be located in the web page itself?

My website needs media permission from the user, and if I'm hosted in a Webview (via Facebook mobile application for example), each application needs to have this permission and grant it to me.

Thanks for the help,
Avi.

Comment: anyone? really appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Opening default browser by WebView requires an implementation on native App. In particular the App developer should override the method [WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) and launch an intent to load the url in a separate browser instead through the WebView.

Comment: That's not what I was asking about. As I need the media permission, I want to ask it by myself and not to have each application I'm included in to ask it for me. the most simple way to do it (that I can think of - please share if you think on additional) is to open the link in the default browser and ask the user to approve it with the browser standard dialog.

Comment: Sorry, please clarify the following: are you the developer of these applications or you have not any control? For "media permission" you mean the android App's manifest media permission?

Comment: I'm not related to the applications. I'm a website developer that offer the users to use their camera in the site and when I'm hosted in a webview I'm not permitted to use the camera unless the application owner (Facebook for example) give me explicit access. 
So if a mobile application shows my website in a webview, I want to open it in the default browser instead.